# What are the currently conjectures around symmetric group?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, conjectures, open-problem, research

I am asking you this question:

> What are the currently conjectures around symmetric group on research?

Indeed I am interested to work on unsolved problems concerning symmetric or alternating groups.

I know it is a specific question and I asked it to a cultural point of view.

So don't hesitate if you have references of unsolved problems concerning symmetric or alternating groups.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess mathoverflow might be a more suitable place to ask this question.

Comment: I'm not sure MO is a good place for the question either. 'What are open problems in finite groups?' is a pretty wide-open question.

Comment: I think it would be quickly closed on MO as being far too broad.

Comment: I don’t know if you’ve looked at the [Kourovka Notebook](https://kourovka-notebook.org), which is regularly updated. The last notice of update I have is from June 24th.

Comment: Thanks for the link to kourovka notebook, there isn't a lot of about symmetric and alternating group. But thanks it is interessing!

Comment: I have edited the original post of this topic to reopened it more precisely on symmetric and alternating groups. May be somebody could reopened it?

Comment: @Lazare I do think this still needs more focus. I am not convinced that this is the place for problem lists, as lots exist already. So you need a new "twist" to the question. For example, you could ask what problem lists there are, or you could ask about problems which are particularly influential. Or something.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is a conjecture that I want draw some attention to, not that I think it is easy.

Let $X(n)$ denote the multiset of irreducible character degrees of $S_n$. Let $m(n)$ denote the largest multiplicity amongst the elements of the set $X(n)$, i.e., the maximal multiplicity of a character degree of $S_n$.

Back in 2008, I proved that, $m(n)\geq n^{1/7}$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

**Conjecture**: There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $m(n)<n^\epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$ (i.e., all $n$).

Answer (score 1):

There are some well-known conjectures concerning the symmetric group $S_n$. Here is one example, see [Shalev](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272565/1-s2.0-S0097316500X00453/1-s2.0-S0097316596900825/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIBt2sT7FbxWK6CW3BSWeF%2FTXkuvvBXiRVqgQp3Wev2lrAiBMAQZLNYTLue68fQ5mfMlEeEXw6rjuUigSBsZpfckCNiq0AwhKEAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIMs2wSHyyMGsJlBT7gKpEDSeyO78JFtIhMkQs2HSHMVx4bcNzQyjjKnZQqM5JZ8VFHgfFnXkIr4ShIi8Hzj2OtQSWWC4BWiwrOmIfBS10KAeMDiCcbcGCXuk%2Bb9rHrnURnwIMclCZi1LxrqUpiclLzVA51FEiCypbRKAwL90PrPR61SfJCQmyBrgiPrFE1xzEYa8RMXYBnVxkAgDpjz550CtBFgVHQfh%2BK2iw0u3T6ZLI%2B5quM9eoUUmLkT7LztsmwWGw2brS3xok%2FqRfPqhVzeHMumcAkV6xqHF9T7v9foZjt5D3t1Gzx3HUCGJ5gIfFK0hgZL6%2B8%2BR95vOzVEi2CNq2McMMNis%2F5uIBma8kOq%2BYQKUX2NZhqPHaZhx1nbzQDPsa7duczkhs80kLrsHUI5aKZWOaFdLjeSqO3YiKJxlQUIRxKIevNjOAB4%2BH9cUBJbvy1bH6RSJpjchBLOTfZaPr4ilnEsMyOEx00IozCU9zdiUPMNbLiaJ9G85V6SVZ2bJY2m2%2BO0XvVjbsoCd18yblWKcyRXySFg%2FrrRMfXodEwq5uR%2BQU67AFNBSQrzTilKLw9OYXwDehW%2F6ADCDnx8UUF7Cmv5%2FYKJdSX9%2Fa0718RCOd%2B3JXxhkJWvnzNixSIRqfZz3RpPUAw5z5G8t8N%2BKuL%2BqUdLaAlgE%2FRMwmLgFQ%2FBiN1eK3i6wp%2BQG%2BE92ZXrYpqNoYGoNerx86SI641tfka047bN%2BwgcIdV1HEnad1yhOxJRSAy3O1Ebod3pQJ4HX0Kkgycf%2BhoBrFf7gOIaS%2F4sCgrwAu05Zbxvdt9zj7Mpf%2FY7ruoJ5SVD02esy5UJF1b7PCTqmJ%2BvDHCqAbvQVDXUjXTm%2FUiStcsSbBXf%2BXg40hRKQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200731T181012Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY2VJ6PXHK%2F20200731%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ccc16ba60dd802ebefe2c920e9d7e4146381c6d87459b1a8b3d00d5aa92ec2d8&hash=4c49ed22ca1702b188f0d14a4b1243ce737b195071d8d3860055635ce1d7af8f&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0097316596900825&tid=spdf-af797511-8407-4bfd-9c2c-b28026ecd764&sid=c7bda74766e4f9461a399c1-ae0b9728e2a3gxrqb&type=client):

**Conjecture 1.** The group $S_n$ has $n^{o(1)}$ conjugacy classes of primitive maximal subgroups.

Edit: This has been proved already, see below, but nevertheless is still an interesting topic.

Comment: This was proved by Liebeck-Martin-Shalev in 2005.

Comment: To add to my short comment, in their paper, L-M-S proved that the number of maximal subgroups in 'curly S', i.e, ones not coming from positive-dimensional subgroup, are bounded in terms of the Lie rank only. This is enough to prove that result.