# Conjectures around number of subgroups of symmetric group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, symmetric-groups, groups-enumeration

I am asking if you know unsolved or recently solved conjectures around numbers of subgroups in symmetric or alternating groups.
In fact, is there a formula depending of $n$ to count subgroups of order $k$ in the symmetric group $S_n$ ? Particularly, how subgroups $S_n$ contains ?

I know it is possible to use GAP to find this on the cases for $n=1,\dots,15$, but i don't know if formulas around these questions have already been discovered.
If you have references on the topic, don't hesitate.

Thanks

Comment: You have already asked about conjectures on $S_n$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775949/what-are-the-currently-conjectures-around-symmetric-group). "How subgroups $S_n$ contains"? Every finite group is a contained in some symmetric group $S_n$. On the number of subgroups of a fixed $S_n$, see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000638).

Comment: [Number of distinct subgroups of symmetric group $S_n$, counting conjugates as distinct](https://oeis.org/A005432); [Enumerating subgroups of the symmetric group](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~mareg/download/papers/symsubs/symsubs.pdf) (Derek Holt)

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is difficult to find a formula for the number of subgroups of $S_n$. However, for $n=p$ the answer is easy. If $n=p$ is prime then $S_p$ contains $(p-1)!/(p-1) = (p-2)!$ subgroups of order $p$.

For the general case, see the answers at MSE so far:

[Enumerating all subgroups of the symmetric group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76176/enumerating-all-subgroups-of-the-symmetric-group)

There are upper bounds for the number by Pyber and Shalev.

See also the paper by [Derek Holt](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1043.2789&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a list of representatives of the conjugacy classes of subgroups of $S_n$ for $n ≤ 18$, including the $7274651$ classes of subgroups of $S_{18}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your references. I known the case n=p, i also read something about $p$-subgroup of $S_n$. Do you think there exist results like that for particularly $n$ ? I mean for exemple for odd numbers ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a conjecture of Pyber that the number of subgroups (or conjugacy classes of subgroups if you prefer!) of $S_n$ is $2^{\frac{n^2}{16}+o(n^2)}$.

It is easy to prove that this is a lower bound: you can do this by looking at elementary abelian two subgroups in which all orbits have length 1 or 2.

I think  the best upper bound proven so far is something like $2^{\frac{n^2}{4}+o(n^2)}$ but I would need to check.

Comment: When you said "elementary abelian two subgroups" you mean isomorphic to the trivial group and $\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ ? 
Thanks a lot for this conjecture, have you got recent references (articles) for your upper bound?

Comment: For a prime $p$, an elementary abelian $p$-group  is an abelian group $G$ with $g^p=1$ for all $g \in G$. It is isomorphic to a direct product of copies of ${\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$. As I said, I am not sure exactly what the best known upper bound is - I will need to hunt around for references.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you re-find your references, don't hesitate to make them here. I'm very interested on this upper bound.

Comment: Another question about this number: There exists a lower-bound (untrivial) for the number of subgroups of $S_n$ ?

Comment: Yes I answered that question in my answer! It would be a good exercise for you to try and prove that, just to try and get a feeel for the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i was focused on your upper-bound! Do you have the reference of the Pyber's work ? (Not necessary if the method is only to use abelian p-group, but maybe there are comments on the upper bound)